# Do type specifications belong in .hrl files?

Tags: types, erlang, header-files, specifications

Do Erlang type specifications belong in .hrl files(which are loaded into any .erl file that needs them) or should they be kept in an Erlang module, and then exported (which would allow them to be used in other modules)? It seems to me that both methods allow achieve the same thing.

- Are there any subtle differences I am missing? (I know that the contents of header files are copied into every file that uses them, essentially duplicating code at compile time).
- Are there times where one method should be used over another?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does matter a bit in that specs are actually used to generate a function/module's documentation with the edoc application.

And if the right spec clause is not above the right function clause edoc will complain and the whole module's documentation generation will fail.

Please think of edoc.

Answer (score 7):

Type specifications (i.e. `-spec` attributes) belong to the module where the function is defined. Period.

Type definitions (`-type`, `-opaque`), on the other hand, could be defined in `.hrl` files, but I think this is usually a poor decision. This would mean, that every module including the header in question would "define" the type locally. This might lead to namespace clashes, when the module already defined a type which is also defined in a header you wanted to include.
Exporting types from modules instead of defining them in `.hrl`s gives you a namespace prefix and disambiguates between types defined locally (`mytype()`) and by external applications/modules (`yourmod:yourtype()` or, sic!, `yourmod:mytype()`).

Usually, when writing an Erlang application or library it's best to define the type in the module that uses it (the most). For types which are exported outside the library, export them from the main library module - if the app is called `myapp`, then make all public types accessible like `myapp:config()`, `myapp:some_record()`.

One more thing comes to my mind: Dialyzer doesn't like bare record definitions - it's advised to explicitly define types for records (so one `-type` for each `-record`). On the other hand, it's convenient to place record definitions in header files, so they can be shared between code in different places (like `src/mymod.erl` and `test/mymod_tests.erl`). In such case I'd define the record in the header file (`src/mymod.hrl` for a private module or `include/mymod.hrl` if the module is part of the application/library public interface), but still define and export the type from the module where it belongs (i.e. `mymod:some_record()`).

The point tkowal raised is also important. If you don't want to expose the internal structure, then the `-opaque` attribute is meant to do just that - it says "don't depend on this type's internal structure". So you just need to define a type with `-opaque` instead of `-type`, export it, and let Dialyzer warn you about each place in the code which accidentally builds a term of that type but doesn't state it explicitly, or about each pattern matching which tries to deconstruct that type outside the module where the type is defined.

Comment: A friendly reminder for all beginners out there: don't forget to export your types if you want to use it like `myapp:mytype()`.

Comment: I ended up here having problems with ex_doc (exit with errors) due to types defined in .hrl files. Your answer reinforced my opinion that we should all keep types definitions in modules. 

Also many editors Erlang extensions display wrong warnings for types defined in hrl files. Most of them properly detects them but trow warnings at you that the types are unused. You will end up sooner or later with a bunch of problems if you use type definitions in hrl files. Great answer. Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter that much. You can put them, where it makes sense.

- If your types are closely connected with record definitions and their internal structure should be known - put them in .hrl files.
- If you don't want to expose internal structure (for example, you used proplists, but you want to change to dicts in the future), it may better to create module with accessor functions and put the type specification there with comment: "don't depend on this type internal structure". You still want to export it to make sure, that other modules use it. Even, if they are using it as a black box.

If you put something in .hrl and other modules depend on it - it is harder to change. When you put it in module, it should be easier to modify and refactor.